# Get TimeStamps when GC (Garbage Collector) starts and finishes in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, garbage-collection, ecmascript-5

How can we get the TimeStamps of every time that the GC starts and finishes its sweep in JavaScript?

I do not want to interfere with its work, only to register to its `start` and `end` **sweep events**, if possible.